# Cannot set property'gcalFeed' of undefined, error from gcal.js

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, gcal

I am using fullcalendar.js when I call gcal.js I am gettting the error in the console, 'Cannot set property'gcalFeed' of undefined' does anyone know what gcalFeed is and what are the values it can be set to?
the following is the code
ar pagefunction = function() {

```
// full calendar

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var hdr = {
    left: 'title',
    center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
    right: 'prev,today,next'
};

var initDrag = function (e) {
    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end

    var eventObject = {
        title: $.trim(e.children().text()), // use the element's text as the event title
        description: $.trim(e.children('span').attr('data-description')),
        icon: $.trim(e.children('span').attr('data-icon')),
        className: $.trim(e.children('span').attr('class')) // use the element's children as the event class
    };
    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    e.data('eventObject', eventObject);

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    e.draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
    });
};

var addEvent = function (title, priority, description, icon) {
    title = title.length === 0 ? "Untitled Event" : title;
    description = description.length === 0 ? "No Description" : description;
    icon = icon.length === 0 ? " " : icon;
    priority = priority.length === 0 ? "label label-default" : priority;

    var html = $('<li><span class="' + priority + '" data-description="' + description + '" data-icon="' +
        icon + '">' + title + '</span></li>').prependTo('ul#external-events').hide().fadeIn();

    $("#event-container").effect("highlight", 800);

    initDrag(html);
};

/* initialize the external events
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

$('#external-events > li').each(function () {
    initDrag($(this));
});

$('#add-event').click(function () {
    var title = $('#title').val(),
        priority = $('input:radio[name=priority]:checked').val(),
        description = $('#description').val(),
        icon = $('input:radio[name=iconselect]:checked').val();

    addEvent(title, priority, description, icon);
});

/* initialize the calendar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: hdr,
    buttonText: {
        prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
    },

    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!

    drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
        }

    },

    select: function (start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
            }, true // make the event "stick"
            );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        // this is the google calender url. 
        // see docs at http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
        // todo getting error check http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/QKPFQ/

        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/herb.williams%40softwaretechnologygroup.com/public/basic'

    },
    eventRender: function (event, element, icon) {
        if (!event.description == "") {
            element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/><span class='ultra-light'>" + event.description +
                "</span>");
        }
        if (!event.icon == "") {
            element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<i class='air air-top-right fa " + event.icon +
                " '></i>");
        }
    },

    windowResize: function (event, ui) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    }
});

/* hide default buttons */
$('.fc-header-right, .fc-header-center').hide();



$('#calendar-buttons #btn-prev').click(function () {
    $('.fc-button-prev').click();
    return false;
});

$('#calendar-buttons #btn-next').click(function () {
    $('.fc-button-next').click();
    return false;
});

$('#calendar-buttons #btn-today').click(function () {
    $('.fc-button-today').click();
    return false;
});

$('#mt').click(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
});

$('#ag').click(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
});

$('#td').click(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
});
```

};

// end pagefunction

// loadscript and run pagefunction
loadScript("js/plugin/fullcalendar/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js", pagefunction);

Comment: Hi, Herb, welcome to [so]. You gotta show how you're "using fullcalendar.js" and how you're "calling gcal.js" so it's possible to reproduce your problem. . . I learned just today that we have to load `gcal` **after** loading `fullcalendar` for gcal to work (don't remember if it was the same error message).

Comment: thanks for the input, I was loading gcal.js before the fullcalender .js and I which to after however I am still getting the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'gcalFeed' of undefined"

Comment: **[edit]** the question to include more information. Here's a helpful guide: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)